# Sum datetime over 24 hours

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way I can add datetime and the sum would be over 24 hours?

here is my script and the talkTime is stored as varchar.

```
select 
cast(sum(cast(left(right(convert(char(19),cast(talkTime as datetime),120),8),2) as int)+
(cast(left(right(convert(char(19),cast(talkTime as datetime),120),5),2) as real)/60)+
(cast(left(right(convert(char(19),cast(talkTime as datetime),120),2),2) as real)/3600)) as datetime)
from table1
```

this is the data that I'm trying to sum up.

```
talkTime
0:45:43
4:19:42
4:21:19
5:52:29
4:59:25
6:06:21
5:03:00
5:51:24
5:18:35
```

The total should be. 42:37:58. But instead I'm getting is this. 1900-02-12 15:11:12.047. I've read that this is due to sql can only store 24 hours on datetime. is there a work around I can use to get my desired output?

Comment: What format and type are your date values? So what do you want your output to be?

Comment: Could you supply some sample data and the desired output?

Comment: Time or datetime is not a good choice of type for durations. Durations should be stored as decimal/int, e.g. rather than storing `hh:mm:ss`, simply store the number of seconds elapsed. so `01:02:03` becomes `3723`. If you want to display 3723 in the format `hh:mm:ss` worry about this in your presentation layer.

Comment: @GarethD datetime is a great way to store duration, you can add them normally and ask for the different parts without calculating. Duration = enddatetime - startdatetime, Although you can't use aggregate directly on datetimes

Comment: @t-clausen.dk it is not. How would you store 25 hours and 30 minutes as a datetime? If start time is relevant, I would agree that if the start time is relevant, storing the start and end dates as a datetime is the best way to do it, but for an arbitrary duration it should be decimal/int.

Comment: I would store it as 1900-01-02 01:30

Comment: Wait guys. I'll edit my question my sample data and my desired output.

Answer (score 2):

If you're simply looking to get the duration between 2 date time values, you can use simple `DATEDIFF` calculations. This is a rather long winded approach that you would ideally modify and hold in a function if you were to use it:

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/06f94/14)</kbd>

**MS SQL Server Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE TalkTime
    ([talkTime] time(4))
;

INSERT INTO TalkTime
    ([talkTime])
VALUES
    ('0:45:43'),
    ('4:19:42'),
    ('4:21:19'),
    ('5:52:29'),
    ('4:59:25'),
    ('6:06:21'),
    ('5:03:00'),
    ('5:51:24'),
    ('5:18:35')
;
```

**Separate the time segments and return a string representation**:

```
DECLARE @hours INT
DECLARE @mins INT
DECLARE @secs INT

SELECT @hours = SUM(DATEDIFF(HOUR, '0:00:00', talktime)) +
((SUM(DATEDIFF(minute, '0:00:00', talktime)) - (SUM(DATEDIFF(hour, '0:00:00', talktime)) *60)) / 60)
FROM TalkTime

SELECT @mins = (SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, '0:00:00', talktime)) - (@hours*60*60))/60
FROM TalkTime

SELECT @secs = (SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, '0:00:00', talktime))) - ((@hours*60*60) + (@mins*60))
FROM    TalkTime

SELECT CAST(@hours AS NVARCHAR(4)) + ':' + CAST(@mins AS NVARCHAR(2)) + ':' +  CAST(@secs AS NVARCHAR(2))
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/06f94/14/0)**:

```
| COLUMN_0 |
|----------|
| 42:37:58 |
```

Comment: Hi. What I'm trying to do is add the datetime fields. which the result would be over 24hours.

Comment: @ElishTorres here's an updated answer with some rather ugly calculations that might help you

Comment: I figured myself what I'm trying to do. Thanks anyways. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  cast(datediff(hour, 0, 
    dateadd(s, sum(datediff(second, 0, talktime)), 0)) as varchar(5))
  + right(convert(char(19),dateadd(s, sum(datediff(second, 0, talktime)),0), 126), 6)
FROM 
  (values(cast('12:55:02' as time)),
    (cast('13:55' as time))) table1(talktime)
```

Result:

```
26:50:02
```

Replace last 2 example rows with your table1

Answer (score 0):

Store the duration in datetime but DATEDIFF() with '1900-01-01' when use

```
DECLARE @StartTime datetime = '2015-01-19 17:18', @EndTime datetime = GETDATE()

SELECT 
    @StartTime AS StartTime,
    @EndTime AS EndTime,
    @EndTime - @StartTime AS Duration,
    DATEDIFF(DAY, '1900-01-01', @EndTime - @StartTime) AS Day, 
    DATEDIFF(HOUR, '1900-01-01', @EndTime - @StartTime) % 24 AS Hour, 
    DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '1900-01-01', @EndTime - @StartTime) % 60 AS Minute, 
    DATEDIFF(SECOND, '1900-01-01', @EndTime - @StartTime) % 60 AS Second, 
    RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar(20), @EndTime - @StartTime, 120), 8) AS Time
```

Result

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your varchar to time, then convert your time to seconds using `DATEDIFF` before you can sum it up:

```
SELECT Seconds = SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, '00:00', CAST(Duration AS TIME)))
FROM T;
```

Then you can then use various conversions to get the result back to a `VARCHAR`, although I would ideally recomend doing this conversion in your presentation layer:

```
CREATE TABLE #T (Duration varchar(7));
INSERT INTO #T (Duration)
VALUES
    ('0:45:43'), ('4:19:42'), ('4:21:19'), ('5:52:29'), ('4:59:25'),
    ('6:06:21'), ('5:03:00'), ('5:51:24'), ('5:18:35');

SELECT  Formatted = STUFF(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), DATEADD(SECOND, Seconds, 0), 108), 
                            1, 2, CAST(FLOOR(Seconds / 3600) AS VARCHAR(5)))
FROM (  SELECT Seconds = SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, '00:00', CAST(Duration AS TIME)))
        FROM #T
    ) AS s;
```

The formatting here does the following:

1. Convert the seconds into a `DATETIME` - `DATEADD(SECOND, Seconds, 0), 108)`
2. Convert this DATETIME into a `VARCHAR` in the format `hh:mm:ss` - `CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), [Datetime]), 108)`.
3. Calculate the number of hours elapsed as a `VARCHAR` - `CAST(FLOOR(Seconds / 3600) AS VARCHAR(5))`
4. Insert these hours into the string in the format `hh:mm:ss` in place of `hh` using `STUFF`

The reason I suggested in a comment that you should store the duration as an integer is because this is what you need to convert it to in order to do anything useful anyway, so you may as well cut out the middle man and avoid having to convert your varchar to time, then your time to an integer every time you need to use a value.

If you can't change your table structure yo ucouldadd a computed column to your table to make calculations easier, e.g.

```
ALTER TABLE T ADD DurationInSeconds AS DATEDIFF(SECOND, '00:00', CAST(Duration AS TIME));
```

And you could put your formatting logic inside its own function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetFormattedDuration] (@Second DECIMAL(15, 2))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
    RETURN 
    (
        SELECT  FormattedDuration = CASE WHEN @Second < 86400 THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), DATEADD(MILLISECOND, (@second  * 1000), '00:00:00.000'), 108)
                                        ELSE STUFF(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), DATEADD(MILLISECOND, (@second  * 1000), '00:00:00.000'), 108), 1, 2, CAST(FLOOR(@Second / 3600) AS VARCHAR(5)))
                                    END
    );
```

Then your query is as simple as:

```
SELECT  Total = (SELECT FormattedDuration 
                FROM dbo.GetFormattedDuration(SUM(DurationInSeconds))
                )
FROM    #T;
```

*I have used an inline table valued function purely for perfomance reasons*

Comment: Is this MsSQL. I'm getting an error. 'SEC_TO_TIME' is not a recognized function name. 'TIME_TO_SEC' is not a recognized function name.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your comment as "Sorry. it is MySQL", rather than "MsSQL" - I will edit

Comment: I figured myself what I'm trying to do. Thanks anyways. :)